# How to UNION a non-union compatible table

Tags: mysql

The question im suppose to answer is, Create a table that results from adding UNION ralational operator to BOOTH and MACHINE.

This are the tables.

BOOTH table
[image: BOOTH table]

MACHINE table
[image: MACHINE table]

Can someone show me the relational algebra equation for this answer. I'm lost :((

Comment: Thank you :). I didn't knew if my professor would let me do this.

Comment: What is a "relational algebra equation"? Why have two table that store basically the same information anyway? My guess is your schema may not be well-designed.

Comment: a relational algebra is showing the database equation in symbols. pi for PRODUCT, sigma for SELECT, etc. Is on the book database systems 12e by carlos coronel and steven morris

Comment: OK.  Interesting.  Have been working in software development for quite a while, using relational databases all that time and working with some very top talent and have never seen anyone in the software development space utilize this notational methodology.  It must be from math folks who move into computer science :)

Comment: :) Where do you work at?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could really just alias the names of the columns from both tables so they are the same.

```
select Machine_Product as Booth_Product, Machine_Price as Booth_Price
from MachineTable
union
select Booth_Product, Booth_Price
from BoothTable
```

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense.